# PHP: замена ссылок в тексте из базы данных

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

В базе данных есть текстовый столбец, в котором хранятся ссылки и текст:

`"Привет всем <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=123">это ссылка на новости the</a> и  "Привет всем <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=321">это ссылка на категорию</a>`

**Задача**: преобразовать эти ссылки:

в `/p123` если `index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=123`

и в `/c321` если `index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=321`

Как это сделать проще всего? Спасибо!))))

Comment: *Как это сделать проще всего?* Обычным `REPLACE()`.

Comment: опиши подробнее)

Comment: ?? `index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=` меняешь на `/p`, а `index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=` на `/c`. Всё.

Comment: опиши полностью пожалуйста, пока не понимаю, поэтому и спрашиваю

Comment: [UPDATE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html), [REPLACE() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace).

Comment: ещё вот это может понадобится https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php

Comment: используется laravel

Comment: Нет смысла тащить все данные на PHP, там изменять, и потом тащить их обратно на MySQL, когда достаточно послать на MySQL одну короткую команду - и он всё сделает сам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите изменить уже готовые данные, то вам будет достаточно такого SQL запроса:

```
UPDATE TableName SET link = REPLACE(REPLACE(link, "index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=", "/c"), "index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=", "/p");
```

Если же вы хотите делать это для будущих записей, то вам нужно будет написать примерно такой PHP код:

```
$str = '<a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=123">это ссылка на новости the</a><a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=321">это ссылка на категорию</a>';
$str = str_replace(["index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=", "index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id="], ["/p", "/c"], $str);

echo $str; //<a href="/p123">это ссылка на новости the</a><a href="/c321">это ссылка на категорию</a>
```